# Need to show data as per column wise in MySQL as per Image

Tags: mysql

[image: Tables with Data]

I have data as main table now how can I show data as per query table. Please help.

Comment: Did you bother to search for conditional aggregation as suggested in your last question?

Answer (score 0):

Hello Please test this:

```
CREATE TABLE MainTable 
(
Code INT, ItemName VARCHAR(30), SalesDate DATETIME, SalesQty INT);
INSERT INTO MainTable VALUES
(1, 'Product-1','2022-01-01',593),
(2, 'Product-2','2022-01-02',1152),
(3, 'Product-3','2022-01-03',1629),
(4, 'Product-4','2022-01-04',4216),
(5, 'Product-5','2022-01-05',1760),
(1, 'Product-1','2022-02-01',1634),
(2, 'Product-2','2022-02-02',1748),
(3, 'Product-3','2022-02-03',2259),
(4, 'Product-4','2022-02-04',2076),
(5, 'Product-5','2022-02-05',1040);

SELECT Code, ItemName,
 (CASE WHEN MONTH(SalesDate) = 1 THEN SUM(SalesQty) END) AS January,
 (CASE WHEN MONTH(SalesDate) = 2 THEN SUM(SalesQty) END) AS February
FROM MainTable
GROUP BY Code, ItemName,SalesDate;
```

Result_Set:
[image: Click here to see the result]